# How to instantiate from a string class name in PHP?

Tags: php

How to create a new instance of the name of the method that returns? Unfortunately I get this error:

> Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Here is my code:

```
class Foo {
  public function selClass(){
    return 'Home()';
  }
}


$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new $foo->selClass();
```

Comment: `'Home()'` is just a string.

Answer (score 9):

Following your example, **here be dragons**:

```
$bar = new ${!${''}=substr($foo->selClass(), 0, -2)};
```

If you use this in your code, you can have job at Google.

Comment: Taking a string to a whole new level

Comment: @leon it's super effective if you're unfortunate to have < PHP 5.4, `static` and `factory` in one line. `public static function factory() { return ${!${''}=(new ReflectionClass(get_called_class()))}->newInstanceArgs(func_get_args()); }`

Comment: I agree with your reflection approach 200% - I just thought that parsing the string to extract `Home` from `Home()` was a stretch. Seems like the OP should adjust the methods and then use your suggestion, without the actual string parsing.

Comment: @leon Thanks, in my opinion question is perfect to be closed, the reason *unclear what you're asking*. If OP put more effort in question, he would have gotten correct answer. This was a sort of joke :) (literal answer)

Comment: Yep, agreed - felt that way when I read it. Sarcasm can be seen when one requires reflected classes and instantiated objects to abide to a protocol that forces a method return to carry two extra chars at its end...

Comment: This needs a "here be dragons" warning, and a note to never actually do this in written code.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
class Home {
  public function run(){
    return 'hello world';
  }
}

class Foo {
  public function selClass(){
    return 'Home';
  }
}


$foo = new Foo();
$barClass = $foo->selClass();
$bar = new $barClass;  

echo $bar->run();  // hello world
```

Note that the name of the class you specify inside `selClass` must appear alone, without parentheses, and that the parentheses after `$barClass` are optional.

Comment: What's the point anyways? Why isn't `return new Home;` right?

Comment: @TOOTSKI I'm not sure I understand your comment. The question is a bit unclear, but I believe OP wants to know how to construct a class given just its name. Presumably this is just sample code.

Comment: You should have specified that `Home()` is not a valid class name and that `new $barClass();` can be written as `new $barClass;` since there are no arguments.

Comment: @TOOTSKI Thanks, I've updated to clarify. Admittedly, PHP isn't my primary language.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Home" without the braces. If it still does not work, try saving it to variable and then calling `new $var`.