# PHP How to create instance of class returned as string from method invocation

Tags: php

How to call something like this:

```
$instance = new ($b->method($id))();
```

where `method(int $id): string` returns class name?

The construct above gives me a syntax error, but this is ok:

```
$className = $b->method($id);
$instance = new $className();
```

I'm just wondering **if** and **how** it can be done.
I was surprised that brackets could not say that content of brackets `$b->method($id)` should be executed first and resulting string used to object instantiating.
I probably will not use it in production code, but I'm still interested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to instantiate from a string class name in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207376/how-to-instantiate-from-a-string-class-name-in-php)
You probably should not use the crazy code provided there...

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. And at least it's better worded and shows more research on the issue.

Comment: What's wrong with doing the _ok_ version? First version is quite unreadable.

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question: Why is it so important that you don't store the class name in a variable? That's probably the cleanest solution. If you wanted, you could write a function that takes the class name as parameter and calls new on it, but that would be much uglier still.

Comment: I'm just wondering if and how it can be done. In PHP it's possible to do many "dynamic" things (like calling method from string etc.).

Comment: Did you try: `$instance = (new $b->method($id))()`?

Comment: After seeing the possible duplicate I've reached the conclusion that if you manage to accomplish it you would have found a legal loophole in the Zend engine.

Comment: This simply hasn't been implemented by the AST lexer. It currently only supports simple variables. This shouldn't be too difficult to implement if you put in a feature request: https://github.com/php-src/php/blob/0eb3c377d49a331282b943dba165b4b9df56fad2/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L239

Comment: @JeffPuckett Thanks, case solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on PHP because 'new' needs a string or variable with a string. 
The () characters are used for aritmethic associations and for parameters on languaje constructions, and you can't assign to new the result of a call to another function.